# How to solve the fragile base class with helper methods

Tags: java, helper

I have understood the fragile Base class problem, and I know that we can solve it using Composition over Inheritance or declaring private method in the superclass.
Now I'm trying to understand how to solve this problem using helper method, so I will put the classic code of fragile base class and then I will put my solution with helper method, tell me if I do something wrong please.

This is the code of a fragile base class (from wikipedia)

```
public class JavaApplicationProvaHello {


    public class A {
      private int i;

      public void inc1(){
          i++;
      }

      public void inc2(){
          inc1();
      }  
    }
    //---------------------------
    public class B extends A{
        @Override
        public void inc1(){
            inc2();
        }
    }
    //------------------------
    public class Test{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
           B b = new B();
           b.inc1();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I change the class A and put two private helper methods which will be called by the public method inc1 and inc2

```
public class A {
  protected int i;

  public void inc1(){
      inc1Helper();
  }

  public void inc2(){
      inc2Helper();
  }  

  private void inc1Helper(){
      i++;
  }

  private void inc2Helper(){
      inc1Helper();
  }
}
```

In my compiler everything works, I was asking myself if this is the best solution to solve fragile base class with helper methods. Thank you for the attention.

Answer (score 1):

"Best" is an opinion.

In my opinion, a better answer would be to leave a Javadoc comment on `inc2()` stating that it calls `inc1()`.

```
/** Increments <code>i</code> by calling <code>inc1()</code> */
public void inc2()
...
```

Then anyone who extends `A` can see that in the documentation. If they miss it, then they will know when they look at the stack trace for their stack overflow exception.

This way still requires a few lines in the file but requires no more actual lines of functional logic code and no more generated byte code. The very Wikipedia article you mention suggests (and for Java, nonetheless) documentation as one of the answers.